# Django: error while trying to access ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to create a twitter like application as a practice project, and following this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1R_bykXHGE&t=35220). I've created following models in my app.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="Relationship", related_name="follow_to",
                                       symmetrical=False, blank=True)


class Relationship(models.Model):
    user_followed = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="followed", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_by = models.ForeignKey("Profile", related_name="follower", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The migrations ran successfully.

After this for testing, I created two users (user1 and user2) with their respective profiles and  made user2 to follow user1. Here's the code for that-

```
Relationship.objects.create(user_followed=user1,followed_by=user2.profile)
```

This relationship was successfully created. I try the following code to try to get followers of user1-

```
user1.profile.followers.all()
```

But above code is giving following errors-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/mayank/.pyenv/versions/dwitter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 535, in __get__
return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
File "/Users/mayank/.pyenv/versions/dwitter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 821, in __init__
self.target_field_name = rel.field.m2m_reverse_field_name()
File "/Users/mayank/.pyenv/versions/dwitter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1554, in _get_m2m_reverse_attr
return getattr(self, cache_attr)
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'
```

I tried following the method mentioned [here](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/), but it is also giving the same error. I'm not sure where have I committed a mistake. I would be thankful if someone can correct me.

Comment: Since you make an m2m to `'self'` both the fk's should point to `Profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you make an `ManyToManyField` to `'self'` both the `ForeignKey`s should point to `Profile`:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    followed = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        related_name='followed',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    followed_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        related_name='follower',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Since now both `ForeignKey`s point to the same model, there is an ambiguity what the *source* field, and what the *target* field is. You resolve this by specifying this with the [**`through_fields=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='Relationship',
        related_name='follow_to',
        related_fields=('followed', 'followed_by')
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True
    )
```

You thus can create a follower `Relation` with:

```
Relationship.objects.create(
    followed=user1.profile,
    followed_by=user2.profile
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm! Though I'm still confused, both in video and article, they were following the method I did earlier and still code was working for them. Don't know how